# C remove() function not working

Tags: c, windows, command-prompt, stdio, file-pointer

I'm trying to implement a program I wrote on my Mac on Windows systems, and I'm running into a lot of trouble with this last function:

```
/* clearFiles */
//  deletes the section files after the program has executed
//  skips any sections listed table that don't appear in the body (b/c no file was written for these)
//  also deletes the table & body files
void clearFiles(section_t *tableArray, int *skipArray, char *tableName, char *bodyName)
{
    int i, status, index;
    char str[SECTNAME];
    char command[SECTNAME];

    index = 0;

    //  clear section files
    for(i=1; tableArray[i].count!=0;i++)
    {
        if(i!=skipArray[index])
        {

            strcpy(str, tableArray[i].shortName);
            strcat(str,".txt");

            status = remove(str);
            if(status!=0)
                printf("Warning! File %s not deleted.\n", str);

        } else index++;
    }

    //  clear table file
    status = remove(tableName);
    if(status!=0)
        printf("Warning! File %s not deleted.\n", tableName);

    //  clear body file
    status = remove(bodyName);
    if(status!=0)
        printf("Warning! File %s not deleted.\n", bodyName);
}
```

The program takes a very large file and first splits it into a table of contents file and a body file. It then takes the body and splits it into hundreds of individual section files, from which it performs the actual task of the program. At the end, I want it to delete all of these extra files, because they just clutter up the directory. It works perfectly on my Unix Mac environment, but when I try to run it in Command Prompt on a PC, my remove() function returns -1 for every section file and doesn't delete it (it does, however, successfully delete the table & body files). I also tried a more brute force method by using     system(del fileName), but this didn't work either, because it says that the file is being used by another process. I can't figure out why these files might be open, as every time fopen() appears, I follow it up with an fclose(). The exception is when checking if the files are open, I use

```
if(fopen(fileName,"r")!=NULL){}
```

Could this be the problem? Is there either a way to check if a file is open without actually opening it, or is there a way to close a file that was checked this way? I tried assigning a dummy pointer to it and coding:

```
dummy = fopen(fileName, "r");
if(dummy!=NULL){}
fclose(dummy);
```

But this didn't work either. Is it possible to pass just a file path to the fclose() function (for example, something similar to fclose(C:\users\USER\desktop\fileName.txt)? Also, I know that the program is attempting to delete the correct fileName, because my error message prints the correct names to the command prompt.

Any input is greatly appreciated!!! Thanks.

NOTE: 
   The tableArray starts at 1 because of a search function implemented in the program that returns an index if found and 0 if not found. In hindsight, it would have been better to return -1 if not found and start the index at zero, but that is a separate issue

UPDATE:

Below is the code used to create the section files:

```
if(fopen(word, "r")==NULL){
    ofile = fopen(word, "w");

    fprintf(ofile, "SECTION %s ", section);

    //go until end of file or until found the next section
    //  bug fix: check the section after that, too (in case the next section isn't there)
    while(fscanf(spec, "%s", word)!=EOF && !cease)
    {
        if(strcmp(word,"SECTION")!=0){
            fprintf(ofile, "%s ", word);
        }
        else{
            fscanf(spec, "%s", word);
            choice = testNumber(spec,word);
            for(j=i+1; tableArray[j].count!=0;j++)
                if(strcmp(word,tableArray[j].shortName)==0)
                    cease = 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(ofile);
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2da4hk1d.aspx) if you get -1 as a result you should be able to check [errno](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) to see why.  What does errno tell you?

Comment: @i_am_jorf it says "Permission denied" for each one.

Comment: `if(fopen(fileName,"r")!=NULL){}` leaves you with an open file; a leaked file stream pointer.  That's bad.  Also, you may not be able to remove open files on Windows.  Check the setting in errno - permission denied might be because the file is open.  At the least, if the file is opened, you need to capture the result and close it: `{ FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r"); if (fp != NULL) fclose(fp); }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's what I was thinking, and that's why I tried the whole FILE *dummy business. Still didn't work. Was I doing that wrong? (The code is above in the original question).

Comment: I got confused about what you're up to at that point.  I think (but I'm not certain — I'm an occasional Windows user, not a Windows programmer) that you can't remove files when a process has the file open.  If there's anywhere in the code that could have the file open, you need to find it and fix it.  I'm really not clear what the dummy code is doing apart from cleaning up a bit; it doesn't really seem to react to the open-ness or closed-ness of the files.  If the file fails to open, `fclose(dummy)` is a bad move (`fclose(NULL)` is not guaranteed to be sane — it could crash your program).

Comment: If you actually have code in the action block, I suggest using `if(fopen(fileName,"r")!=NULL) { …; }` (or type `...` instead of `…`); that makes it clear that there is some activity, albeit not shown.  But the fact that you don't assign the result of `fopen()` to a variable means you can't close the file you just opened, which is bad news everywhere.

Comment: How are you creating the file?  Can you post that code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i apologize for the confusion. Yes, I should have included "...", and I will in the future. What I was trying to convey was that when I created a dummy variable to assign this statement to, it still didn't fix the problem. I've scanned my document with a ctrl+f search to find all fopen statements, and all of them come with an fclose, except for the abovementioned tests

Comment: @i_am_jorf I've updated the question so it is included at the bottom

Comment: Once you have fixed the file handle leak, check permissions on the file you are trying to overwrite

Comment: OK, it seems I have fixed the problem through using the access() function in lieu of fopen, and my program works almost every time (it still works perfectly on my Mac but on the PC I'm running into one bug). When I attempt to use remove() to delete the files at the end of the program, occasionally remove() will fail to delete the file, but it will still return 0, indicating that it has successfully removed it. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you can perfectly **remove(2)** an open file.  At least all unix/Linux/BSD/POSIX system allows that.  Only when the file is last closed, the kernel will reclaim the blocks belonging to that file.  Also, in case of not being the last link to the file, it will not be physically erased if you **remove(2)** it.

Comment: The most probable thing that can be happening here is that you don't have a file named like that.  Just change the `if(status!=0)
                printf("Warning! File %s not deleted.\n", str);` for this code `if (status) printf("Warning: %s: %s\n", str, strerror(errno));`  and the system will show you the reason it couldn't erase your file.  `#include <errno.h>` and `#include <string.h>`  for the `errno` variable and `strerror()` function.

Comment: @LuisColorado: I know that.  So does the OP.  The code works on Mac.  It doesn't on Windows.  The issue is all about "why does code that works on Unix not work on Windows?"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, probably the implementation of posix in windows (the function is implemented to comply with it) is far from complete.  I don't know about the implementation of posix by windows nor the libraries you are using (I know about three possible different implementations, one from Microsoft, one from cygwin and one from mingw)